# How can I switch over from one Azure SQL instance to another with zero downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible in any way to switch over to a new Azure SQL instance with zero downtime?

I have been exploring ways to at least get a continuously uptodate secondary instance.

I believe mainly with the geo-replication feature it is possible to keep a secondary instance in sync with the primary Azure SQL instance.

But as far I understand the only way to promote the secondary instance to the new primary you will need to initiate a failover process. This unfortunately causes many minutes of downtime.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the FOG connection-string - or single-instance connection-string? Have you experimented with using the failover secondary for read-only queries?

Comment: Well, here it says it might take maximum 30 seconds of downtime: "This process normally should complete within 30 seconds or less.

There's a short period during which both databases are unavailable, on the order of 0 to 25 seconds, while the roles are switched. "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal?view=azuresql&tabs=portal#initiate-a-failover

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much a failover scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal?view=azuresql&tabs=portal

Another way, is by adding a caching layer (in case it's not there), then start writing to the cache first, then write to the database (the new one once it's ready).

This is known as write through strategy:

[image]